# Can vim syntax regions be made to touch/overlap?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

So a while ago I had decided to learn more about how vim's syntax files work, by creating my own.  My goal was to create a simple syntax file that would split the file into 3 parts based on delimiters, and include pre-existing syntax files for two of those three parts.

This is an example file:

```
Some text, unstyled

==================== Log
(Output of git log)

==================== Diff
(Output of diff)
```

The goal was to apply `git.vim` to just the log, and `diff.vim` to just the diff, excluding the two headers.<sup>1</sup>  This is what my syntax file ended up looking like:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syntax include @gitlog $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/git.vim
syntax region GitLog
    \ start=/^===* Log/
    \ end=/^===* Diff/
    \ contains=@gitlog

syntax include @gitdiff $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/diff.vim
syntax region Diff
    \ start=/^===* Diff/
    \ end=/\n\n/
    \ contains=@gitdiff

let b:current_syntax = "logdiff"
```

Note how `end` on the first region is the same as `start` on the second region.  This doesn't work; the second region is apparently not detected and syntax highlighting is not applied.

I can make it work by loosening the regex to `end=/^===/` and `start=/=== Diff/`, so that the regions don't touch, but don't particularly like that - it's less obvious that one is supposed to start where the other ends.

Is there a way to allow two region definitions to touch the same characters (and/or make the matching edges exclusive instead of inclusive) or am I stuck with the looser regex?

<sub><sup>1</sup>(Yes, I know `git.vim` includes `diff.vim`, but this was a learning exercise)</sub>

Comment: I think this should be possible either by using an "Region End" offset to make the edges exclusive (see `:h :syn-pattern-offset`), or by changing the GitLog region to extend to the end of the file, and the Diff region to be entirely inside the GitLog region. I couldn't get either of these methods to work, though.

Comment: Testing it was made somewhat harder by the fact that--as you note--git.vim already highlights diff output. Might be an idea to alter your example accordingly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell Vim regex engine where to start next match.

So far I know there are 2 ways:

1. Use `\ze` to set the end of a match:

   ```
   syntax region GitLog
       \ start=/^===* Log/
       \ end=/\ze^===* Diff/
       \ contains=@gitlog
   ```
2. Use positive lookahead, `\@=`, which is called zero-width matching in Vim:

   ```
   syntax region GitLog
       \ start=/^===* Log/
       \ end=/\(^===* Diff\)\@=/
       \ contains=@gitlog
   ```

So the end-of-match "pointer" kind of rewinds to the beginning of `^===* Diff` line, such that `region Diff`'s `start` will start its matching at `^===* Diff` line again.